# What's wrong with my Insert command

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to insert data into my database using a `DataGridView` in C#. However when I click the save button appears the following error message:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
>
> HResult = -2147217900
>    Message = Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
>    Source = Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
>    ErrorCode = -2147217900

Here's the code I have:

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Stock.accdb");
    con.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_insert.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO product(OV,Reference,Cod_Client,Client,Qtd,Type_product,Posicion_product,) VALUES ('" + dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["OV"].Value + "','" + dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Reference"].Value + "','" + dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Cod_Client"].Value + "','" + dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Client"].Value + "','" + dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Qtd"].Value + "','" + dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Type_product"].Value + "','" + dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Posicion_product"].Value + " ' ", con);    
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what is that `,` here  at the end of `Type_product,Posicion_product,)` I vote to close this typo

Comment: Use parameters instead of string concatenation.  It makes it impossible to know what could be wrong unless you know what values are getting inserted. Plus it open the door for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: But even without this , it does not work

Comment: Ok,.. the closing bracket of `VALUES (` is missing aswell but go with S.Akbari's answer and use parameters

Comment: What's *not* wrong with it ? Extra comma before the ") VALUES", not closing parenthesis, using concatenated string to make an insert inside C#, possibly not converting datatypes to string correctly in order to run the insert, adding an extra space on the last item of the insert, not treating possible exceptions leaving the connection hanging, not using parameters, also, MS Access. Also, if you happen to know how to debug strings in your tool, probably Visual Studio, it would be nice to see the actual formed string before the insert. This is not a C# error, this is an Access SQL error.

Answer (score 1):

You have one stray `,` after `Posicion_product` and also you missed the closing bracket of `VALUES` in your insert statement. Remove it. Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO product(OV,Reference,Cod_Client,Client,Qtd,Type_product,Posicion_product) VALUES (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["OV"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Reference"].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["Cod_Client"].Value);
//And continue for other parameters
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["OV"].Value;
```

Comment: I've done it, I added the other parameters. But still get the same error:

Comment: Message = parameter @a has no default.

Comment: @satbr Can you update your question with your new code? I guess you missed something.

Comment: @satbr Also make sure that `dataGridView_insert.Rows[i].Cells["OV"].Value` is not null.